# Finding the degree of a Maclaurin polynomial of $\ln(x)$ for the error to $\lt0.001$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I've got a problem where I have to find the degree of the Maclaurin polynomial (meaning it's centered at $c = 0$, correct?) of $\ln(1.25)$ such that the error is less than 0.001.

I think I have a fairly good understanding of how you find the degree required to match that criteria for other functions, but I'm confused as to how you would find the Maclaurin polynomial for $\ln(x)$ since 0 is outside the domain of natural log and also since $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is undefined at 0.

Am I misunderstanding part of this problem, and how can I go about solving this?

Comment: You can't expand $\ln(x)$ into a Maclaurin Polynomial or Series because it's not defined at $x=0$. Are you sure the question isn't asking for $\ln(1+x)$?

Comment: @AndrewLi That's what I thought, but as far as I can tell it's $ln(x)$. We're only given the instruction to find the degree of the Maclaurin polynomial to have the error less than 0.001 at the given x and $\ln(1.25)$. It's possible that it intends $\ln(1+x)$ but it's not clear in that case.

Comment: Could you give more context, if any? Did an instructor just ask to approximate $\ln(1.25)$ or did they explicitly mention $\ln(x)$ (which if they did I'd be a bit concerned)?

Comment: @AndrewLi The exact wording is "determine the degree of the Maclaurin polynomial required for the error in the approximation of the function at the indicated value of x to be less than 0.001" and then we're given just straight $\ln(1.25)$

Comment: I'd say go with $\ln(1+x)$. It's a common Maclaurin Series, and so: $\ln(1 + 0.25)$. Then, because it's an alternating series, the first omitted term is the error bound.

Answer (score 1):

*Just added for your curiosity since copper hat already gave the answer.*

Say that you want the result to be in an error smaller than $\epsilon$, you need to find $n$ such that 
$${x^{n+1} \over n+1} < \epsilon$$ Sooner or later, you will learn that
$${x^{n+1} \over n+1} = \epsilon\implies n=-1-\frac{W\left(-\frac{\log (x)}{\epsilon }\right)}{\log (x)}$$ where appears [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
Since the argument is large, you can use the given expansion
$$W(y)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\cdots$$
where $L_1=\log(y)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$.

For illustration, let $x=0.25$ and $\epsilon=10^{-k}$ and apply the formula. This would give
$$ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & n \\
 1 & 0.412 \\
 2 & 1.626 \\
 3 & 2.986 \\
 4 & 4.424 \\
 5 & 5.910 \\
 6 & 7.428
\end{array}
\right)$$ and you need to use $\lceil n\rceil$ for the final result.

Answer (score 0):

For $|x| <1$ we have $\log(1+x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} {x^k \over k}$.

Since the series is alternating, we see that
$|\log(1+x) - \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} {x^k \over k} | \le {|x|^{n+1} \over n+1}$.

Choose $n$ such that ${ {1 \over 4^{n+1}} \over n+1} < {1 \over 1000}$. I believe $n=3 $ will suffice.

Comment: @AndrewLi: I am fairly sure that is what they want.